# Python - Solve time-dependent matrix differential equation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, ode

I am facing some problems solving a time-dependent matrix differential equation.
The problem is that the time-dependent coefficient is not just following some time-dependent shape, rather it is the solution of another differential equation.

Up until now, I have considered the trivial case where my coefficient G(t) is just G(t)=pulse(t) where this pulse(t) is a function I define. Here is the code:

```
# Matrix differential equation
def Leq(t,v,pulse): 
    v=v.reshape(4,4) #covariance matrix 
    M=np.array([[-kappa,0,E_0*pulse(t),0],\.  #coefficient matrix 
                [0,-kappa,0,-E_0*pulse(t)],\
                [E_0*pulse(t),0,-kappa,0],\
                [0,-E_0*pulse(t),0,-kappa]])
    
    Driff=kappa*np.ones((4,4),float) #constant term
    
    dv=M.dot(v)+v.dot(M)+Driff #solve dot(v)=Mv+vM^(T)+D
    return dv.reshape(-1)  #return vectorized matrix

#Pulse shape
def Gaussian(t):
    return np.exp(-(t - t0)**2.0/(tau ** 2.0))

#scipy solver
cov0=np.zeros((4,4),float) ##initial vector
cov0 = cov0.reshape(-1);   ## vectorize initial vector
Tmax=20 ##max value for time
Nmax=10000 ##number of steps
dt=Tmax/Nmax  ##increment of time
t=np.linspace(0.0,Tmax,Nmax+1)

Gaussian_sol=solve_ivp(Leq, [min(t),max(t)] , cov0, t_eval= t, args=(Gaussian,))
```

And I get a nice result. The problem is that is it not exactly what I need. Want I need is that dot(G(t))=-kappa*G(t)+pulse(t), i.e. the coefficient is the solution of a differential equation.

I have tried to implement this differential equation in a sort of vectorized way in Leq by returning another parameter G(t) that would be fed to M, but I was getting problems with the dimensions of the arrays.

Any idea of how should I proceed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you have the right idea, you just have to split and join the state and derivative vectors.

```
def Leq(t,u,pulse): 
    v=u[:16].reshape(4,4) #covariance matrix 
    G=u[16:].reshape(4,4) 
    ... # compute dG and dv
    return np.concatenate([dv.flatten(), dG.flatten()])
```

The initial vector has likewise to be such a composite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still, the G parameter is not an array for a given time, rather a value. Therefore, I changed it for G=u[16:]  having defined the initial state as G_0=np.zeros((1,1),float).reshape(-1). Still, when I put this G parameter in the M matrix  I get this error:  VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  M=np.array([[-kappa,0,G,0],\

Comment: If `G` is a scalar it would be most helpful to keep it as scalar most of the time. Thus just `G=u[16]` and `np.concatenate([dv.flatten(), [dG]]`.